# Google Trends valid geos

Tags: google-trends

I'm looking for a list of all valid `geo` values for sub-national units for Germany for the Google Trends API.

All ISO 3166 values seem to work -- the 16 German states that is -- but at least in PR Google is also showing [data for cities](https://trends.google.com/trends/story/DE_cu_tXlX6HABAACSEM_en)

Answer (score 0):

List of all valid geos for the API available [here](https://serpwow.com/docs/search-api/reference/google-trends-geo).